# Отказ в доступе к переносу архива в папку

Tags: python, ос

Я пытаюсь переместить файлы из одной директории в другую, но у меня ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dmitr\Desktop\PROGRAMMM\ch.py", line 7, in <module>
    os.replace('test1.zip', 'C:/Program Files/Google/test1.zip')
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'test1.zip' -> 'C:/Program Files/Google/test1.zip'
```

Вот код:

```
import os

os.replace('test1.zip', 'C:/Program Files/Google/test1.zip')
```

Comment: Обычно запись в Program Files без административных прав запрещена. Поэтому либо запускайте скрипт от администратора, либо копируйте куда-то в другое место.

Comment: Или читайте UAC повышение привилегий - это можно делать как програмно так и вручную, но это будет другой вопрос уже.